# create geojson using simple json java

Tags: java, json, eclipse, geojson

I would like to create the following geojson using the simple-json-1.1.1 jar.

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
            "name": "ESPG:4326"
            }
    },
    "features":[

    {
        "type":"Feature",
        "geometry":{
                "type":"Point",
                "coordinates":[55,55]
                },
        "properties":{
                "desc":"something"}
                }
    ]
}
```

Any ideas on how to do that?Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code to create the geojson mentioned above is the following:

```
JSONObject featureCollection = new JSONObject();
featureCollection.put("type", "FeatureCollection");
JSONObject properties = new JSONObject();
properties.put("name", "ESPG:4326");
JSONObject crs = new JSONObject();
crs.put("type", "name");
crs.put("properties", properties);
featureCollection.put("crs", crs);

JSONArray features = new JSONArray();
JSONObject feature = new JSONObject();
feature.put("type", "Feature");
JSONObject geometry = new JSONObject();

JSONArray JSONArrayCoord = new JSONArray();

JSONArrayCoord.add(0, 55);
JSONArrayCoord.add(1, 55);
geometry.put("type", "Point");
geometry.put("coordinates", JSONArrayCoord);
feature.put("geometry", geometry);

features.add(feature);
featureCollection.put("features", features);
```